# Creating a 2D dynamic array of lists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to implement a 2D dynamic array of lists in Java to store a list of Course objects for a given Student and Week object.

Something along the line, 
`List<List<List<Course>>> listOfCoursesInWeekForStudent = new ArrayList<List<List<Course>>>();`

Could you please show me how to create such a structure, and perform simple operations on it including add and get.

Thank you

Comment: Just use the code you showed, it would work. You can add and get `List<List<Course>>` elements. But I'm not sure whether this structure actually is appropriate in your context, what do you want to achieve with it? Can you give some small example data?

Comment: use a Map instead, having that many level of nesting makes things a bit more complicated.

Comment: I would like to have access to a list given two objects used as indices, e.g. listOfJobs [Employee][Week] would contain a list of Job objects. Will perhaps try with a map.

Comment: Looks like 3D to me.

Comment: Looks like a **nested map** (a map with two keys), relatively straightforward to implement. I'm sure you find some examples using a small google search. Here is one example: [NestedMap2.java](https://github.com/ultimate-pa/ultimate/blob/dev/trunk/source/Library-UltimateUtil/src/de/uni_freiburg/informatik/ultimate/util/datastructures/relation/NestedMap2.java). It's basically just a `Map<K1, Map<K2, V>>`, nothing that special.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please show me how to create such a structure, and perform simple operations on it including `add` and `get`.

The data-structure is `List<List<List<Course>>>`, so it is a `List` containing elements of type `List<List<Course>>`.

You create it exactly like you've shown, using:

```
List<List<List<Course>>> listOfListOfListOfCourses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Adding and getting elements works as usual, just have in mind that the elements are of type `List<List<Course>>`:

```
List<List<Course>> element = ...
// Add element
listOfListOfListOfCourses.add(element);
// Get index of element
int index = listOfListOfListOfCourses.get(element);
```

However, as you might have noticed, the data-structure is **complicated**. I'm sure in your exact context there is a more appropriate data-structure. Unfortunately you didn't provide additional information about your specific task. You may provide it and leave a comment.

---

### Example

Let's try to create a simple example in order to see how such a data-structure could be of use. Therefore

```
List<Course>             // All courses of one semester
List<List<Course>>       // All semesters of one university
List<List<List<Course>>> // All universities of one country
```

In this specific example you easily see that it would be of great help if you create some small **wrapper classes** like

```
public class Semester {
    private List<Course> mCourses;

    public Semester(List<Course> courses) {
        this.mCourses = courses;
    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return this.mCourses;
    }
}

public class University {
    private List<Semester> mSemesters;

    public University(List<Semester> semesters) {
        this.mSemesters = semesters;
    }

    public List<Semester> getSemesters() {
        return this.mSemesters;
    }
}
```

Using this your data-structure breaks down to

```
List<University> // Universities of one country
```

Far more easy to read and understand.